# Как вывести изображение на экран?

Tags: python, изображения, pyqt, opencv, matplotlib

Как вывести изображение на экран?

**Задача**: имеется файл **result.png**, его необходимо выводить на экран много раз (т.к. файл будет меняться). 
Необходим быстрый и самый оптимизированный способ, который способен выводить много раз.

Я пытался уже решить задачу:

- Первой моей попыткой был `PIL` со встроенной функцией `show()`. У меня как раз само изображение создавалось через `PIL`, и я решил заменить функцию `save` на `show`. Больше **`1`** изображения в секунду не может выводить изображения, зависает.
- Второй попыткой был `OpenCV2` с функцией `imshow()`. Окно создавал, но зависал, даже если нужно было вывести всего лишь **`1`** кадр, не меняясь.
- Третей попыткой был `Matplotlib`. Выдавал хорошие результаты с **`1`** кадром в секунду, но когда количество кадров в секунду повысилось до **`2-3`**, окна перестал закрывать, а изображения не выводил.

Comment: с помощью какой библиотеки создавали окно?

Comment: @AbuSuleiman какое окно?

Comment: вы упомянули об окне в вопросе, как вы его создали, с помощью какой библиотеки, tkinter?

Comment: @AbuSuleiman если речь идет про вторую попытку, то окно создается через OpenCV2

Comment: Я знаю как вывести на tkinter

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен что правильно понял вашу задачу, так как не понимаю как файл **result.png** будет меняться.

В моем примере есть список (`self.listImg`) изображений,
из которого в дополнительном потоке рандомно выбирается одно и
передается в основной поток для отображения.
Скорость передачи вы можете отрегулировать.

Прежде чем запустить мой пример, убедитесь, что вы установили ***`PyQt5`***

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

***`PyQt`*** — реализация фреймворка ***`Qt`*** для языка ***`Python`***.

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from random import choice
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Thread(QThread):
    updateSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str)        

    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__()
        self.num = num
        # поставьте свои  result.png, ... vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.listImg = ["Ok.png", "im.png", "lena.jpg", "boy.jpg", "fg.png"]

    def run(self):
        self.keepRunning = True
        while self.keepRunning:
            img = choice(self.listImg)
            self.num += 1
            self.updateSignal.emit(self.num, img) 
            self.msleep(100)                # миллисекунд, попробуйте 1000 и 10
                
    def stop(self):
        self.keepRunning = False
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 380, 280))
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        
        self.v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.v_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Запустить.')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.go_clicked)
        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton('Остановить.')
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop_clicked)
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1)

        self.num = 0
        self.thread = Thread(self.num)
        self.thread.updateSignal.connect(self.add_label) 

    def go_clicked(self):
        self.thread.start()
        
    def stop_clicked(self):
        self.thread.stop()        

    def add_label(self, num, img):
        label = QLabel()
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1E5F74;")
        pix = QPixmap(img).scaled(380, 250, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        label.setPixmap(pix)
        
        labelNum = QLabel('<h1 style="color: #fff">{}<\h1>'.format(num), label)

        self.v_layout.insertWidget(0, label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 310)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В коде имеются ошибки (связанные с тем, что я не уточнил данные): 1. суть самого способа, что должен показываться кадр, окно должно закрываться, рендерится новый кадр, и снова показываться кадр (но другой), закрываться, и т.д., тут же я не могу вставить "свои result.png", потому что он у меня один, а после показывания кадра, должен показываться другой, после рендера. 2. пользователь НЕ ДОЛЖЕН прокручивать ползунок, все должно быть автоматическим. 3. кнопка "Запустить" тоже должна нажиматься сама.

Comment: @TheNick-Ник, вы просили показать способ, я вам показал и все что вы пишите (почему-то в комментариях, а не в теле вопроса) легко реализуется в моем примере.